# Ethernet Connection has Stopped Working

Tags: networking, router, internet, ethernet, modem

My network setup is as follows:

ISP: Rogers Cable

Rogers provides a router with my current internet package. It's their "Rocket" model router, which appears to be a Hitron CGN 4, according to [this](http://communityforums.rogers.com/t5/forums/forumtopicpage/board-id/Getting_connected/thread-id/23021) forum. I was informed by a Rogers employee that I must connect the coaxial cable to this particular router in order to receive service. Connected to this router (which is operating in bridge mode), are two Asus RT-AC87U Routers, casting independent SSIDs. I've read that this might be a problem since I have one router "bridging" two other routers which don't share an SSID (and thus don't share IPs). At any rate, this setup had worked well for the better part of a year. From one of the 87Us an ethernet cable passes through an exterior wall, into a PVC conduit, re-enters the building through another exterior wall, and then connects directly to my laptop's ethernet port.

Recently, I lost connection to the internet, and the router too. Windows 10 only reported "identifying network" thereafter. I looked for answers online, and came across someone suggesting to disconnect the computer's power supply for at least 30 seconds, and then retry the connection. I did this to no avail. I ended up resetting the router to its factory settings, and then set my preferred settings (SSID and whatnot). I tried to reconnect and it worked, for a few days. Now, the same problem has occured. The internet connection was lost, although the SSID was still shown. I disconnected and reconnected the cable to my laptop, and the "identifying network" message popped up. This has switched to "unidentified network, no internet". The wireless connections are working flawlessly, both the 3G and 5G streams.

Any advice that would let me avoid this issue is appreciated, since I have no interest in resetting my router every few days D:

thanks,

Lennart

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to figure out the answer, at least for my particular instance.

I followed Step 2 outlined [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/network-connection-shows-that-it-is-connected-but/52e60042-2666-4eaf-80be-193b26db10be?auth=1). This did not work immediately. 
I then followed the advice in [this](http://www.eightforums.com/network-sharing/18945-error-when-resetting-tcp-ip-stack.html) forum, and took control over netsh.exe, changed the permissions and ran a reset. This appears to have solved the problem. Thanks to everyone who took the time to read through my question, and I hope this helps somebody else in the future.